# Unable to compile project using universal framework in Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have a framework, it's developed in `Swift` and `Objective-C`. I created a fat framework for both and if I try to use it in a project, I am getting the error like:

> Could not find module for architecture x86_64 found arm64,arm,arm7

for both frameworks. I am using Xcode 10.2.

Comment: Seem like your framework wasn't built for the simulator.

Comment: No, i build it for both device and simulator. Also i checked the architecture of that framework, its showing both simulator and device architectures.

Comment: Also its working fine in xcode 10.1

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: No, i just ran the app in real device only.

Comment: I am facing the same issue?wil it work in 10.1?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re building a framework containing Swift code and using lipo to create a binary that supports both device and simulator platforms, you must also combine the generated Framework-Swift.h headers for each platform to create a header that supports both device and simulator platforms. (48635615)
For example, if you’ve built:

```
- iOS/Framework.framework
- iOS Simulator/Framework.framework
```

Take:

```
- iOS/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h
- iOS Simulator/Framework.framework/Framework-Swift.h
```

Create a new:

```
- iOS + iOS Simulator/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h
```

The contents of the new Framework-Swift.h should be:

```
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
<contents of original iOS Simulator/Framework.framework/Framework-Swift.h>
#else
<contents of original iOS/Framework.framework/Framework-Swift.h>
#endif
```

Credit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Just run into the same issue, was able to fix it using the script stored here:

https://gist.github.com/quangDecember/9f7d65964b7df8d71c4a1cfd4f95c0ee

Just replace your script that creates a fat framework with the one from the link. This works perfect for me. XCode 10.2

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue, the only option was to ran the app in a real device. But if you just want to build the project, then choose the "Generic iOS Device" option and no the "iPhone 6", "iPhone 7" or others.

There's not really a solution for this except ask for the framework's owner to release a version with an architecture x86_64.